# Acquire factors for each level of a character vector

Tags: r

Given the following dataset:

```
Ind <- c(rep("deima1",5), rep("deima2", 5), rep("eryt1", 5), rep("eryt2",5))
Sp <-  c(rep("P. deimaticus",10), rep("P. erythros", 10))

Groups <- data.frame(Ind, Sp)
```

For each level of `Groups$Ind`, I'd like to acquire the correspondent species from `Groups$Sp` and store it on a list of factors. The result should have the same length of `levels(Groups$Ind)`.

```
> result
```

`[1] "P. deimaticus" "P. deimaticus" "P. erythros" "P. erythros"`

The problem seems quite straightforward in my mind, however I just can't think of any function that would do the trick. I've tried several different ways of loop this, but something seems to be missing.

Comment: Im not sure if I understand your question correctly, you just want to store the levels of Sp in a list?

Comment: Not quite. I want a list of answers to the question: To which species (`Sp`) does each individual (`Ind`) belong? Therefore, I would end up with a list that has the same length of `levels(Groups$Ind)`, but with names of species instead of individuals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
lapply(split(Groups, Groups$Ind), function(x) unique(as.character(x[["Sp"]])))
$deima1
[1] "P. deimaticus"

$deima2
[1] "P. deimaticus"

$eryt1
[1] "P. erythros"

$eryt2
[1] "P. erythros"
```

Or you may want to store the information in a data frame.

```
dt <- as.data.frame(table(Groups))
# Subset the data for Freq > 0
subset(dt, Freq > 0)
     Ind            Sp Freq
1 deima1 P. deimaticus    5
2 deima2 P. deimaticus    5
7  eryt1   P. erythros    5
8  eryt2   P. erythros    5
```

Comment: This is definitely on the right direction! 
Is there a way I could store these results as a character vector?

Comment: @PedroRocha You can replace `lapply` with `sapply`. However, if there are more than one species names associated with one `Ind`, you still need to use a list to store the information.

Comment: @PedroRocha Please see my update. This is probably not what you want, but I think storing such information in a data frame is useful.

Comment: tabling the data did it! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rep`

```
Ind <- c(rep("deima1",5), rep("deima2", 5), rep("eryt1", 5), rep("eryt2",5))
Sp <-  c(rep("P. deimaticus",10), rep("P. erythros", 10))

Groups <- data.frame(Ind, Sp)

Grp_sp <- levels(Groups$Sp)

rep(Grp_sp, length.out = length(levels(Groups$Ind)) )
```

Comment: This solution only apply for the example I provided. I'm looking for a solution that would work on any given dataset